# Changing actionBar theme to Holo.Light?

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

I need some help with changing the actionbar theme. Currently its holo dark, but i want it to be holo light. I have set

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">
        @android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar
    </item>        
</style>
```

in /styles. But then i need to set it somewhere in the android manifest file, but i dont know where. Cause the action bar is a part of a bigger activity, and the activity has a holo light theme, just not the action bar. Anyone?

Answer (score 15):

What is important to know about setting themes is that by default when you create a project there are 3 folders created under Values: `values`, `values-v11`, and `values-v14`.

The first thing one does by default, is to open the `styles.xml` under the `values` folder. That is where we go wrong. See, because there are **3 folders** for the value files, the Android System will attempt to load the styles defined on the folder that is appropriate for the current system setup. That is, if you run the application on a Nexus Running API level 17, the styles loaded will come from `values-v14` and **NOT** from `values`.

Therefore, you must edit each `styles.xml` file under each folder, to ensure that the theme is loaded correctly regardless of the API level.

Your `styles.xml` for `values-v14` should look like this:

```
<resources>
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: Simple clear and elegant answer.. 

I'm searching for this around a day, your answer helped me. Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your manifest file, add the attribute `android:theme="@style/ActionBar"` inside your `<activity>` tag, if you want the theme to be applied to than one activity only.

```
<activity 
    android:name="YourActivityName"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBar"
/>
```

If you want the theme to be applied to all the activities in the app, add the attribute inside your `<application>` tag

```
<application 
    android:label="YourAppLabel"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBar" 
/>
```